# Why is an extra space getting removed in sed substitution command

Tags: sed

I have a data file that has following data in it:

```
abcd.vc.9902 03493092 90239 m
abc 131323 78202 g
cdb.5491-3 03402394 23241 k
```

I am trying to remove the digits that begin with space. So the command I wrote was

```
sed 's/ [0-9]*//g' data
```

That produces the following output

```
abcd.vc.9902m
abcg
cdb.5491-3k
```

If you notice, it got rid of space before the last letter. The output I desire is:

```
abcd.vc.9902 m
abc g
cdb.5491-3 k
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `*` with a `+` (and escape it if you are using just `sed`, not `sed -r`, as `+` is an extended Regex pattern):

```
sed 's/ [0-9]\+//g' data
```

Or

```
sed -r 's/ [0-9]+//g' data
```

In Regex `*` indicates zero or more match of the preceding token, so in your case if there is no match i.e. no digits after space its being matched too.

On the other hand, if you use `+`, you are matching (at least) one or more digits after a space so you will get the desired result.

Comment: What happens if we remove the ` +` ?

Comment: @Raphael Then it will match a space and a single digit only..

Comment: Then the '+' means that it will keep on matching the digits, right? i.e., [0-9] [0-9] [0-9]...

Comment: @Raphael Spot on..it just ensures that there is at least one match which the `*` does not..

Comment: @heemayl Thanks for the explaination. I totally forgot that * matches 0 or more. I like your approach of using the plus. But what if I rather used this:
**sed 's/ [0-9][0-9]*//g' data**
Should do the same thing right?